# create blank array and assign values in a loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, syntax-error

I am trying to create a blank array so I can fill it with values fetched from the database in a loop. this is my code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $email, $username, $password);

$user = array[];

        while($stmt->fetch)
        {
            $user[name] = $name;
            $user[email] = $email;
            $user[username] = $username;
            $user[password] = $password;
        }
```

however it gives me this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting '(' in /home/cardplan/public_html/android/FetchUserData.php on line 26

line 26 is this one

```
 $user = array[];
```

Comment: Please do some search before asking question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PHP syntax to create an empty array is `$user = array();`, not `$user = array[];`. See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) for additional details.